# Multistage docker build with transfer of installed libraries

Tags: docker, dockerfile, homebrew

I'm using a multi stage docker file. As so:

```
FROM linuxbrew/brew
WORKDIR home/../
RUN brew update
RUN brew install go-task/tap/go-task
RUN brew install helmfile
RUN brew install k3d
RUN brew install kubectl

FROM docker
COPY --from=0 /usr/local /usr/local
RUN task --version
```

In the first stage I install a bunch of libraries using homebrew. Then in the second stage I then want to transfer the libraries to a 'docker in docker' image. However the installed libraries don't seem to be available in the final docker image:

The final line `task --version` fails saying `task: not found`. Why is it not found?

(I would just use apk in the docker image, but helmfile isn't available from apk. If there is an alternative approach to this problem I would be interested to hear it - thanks!)

Comment: If you're doing this just because `helmfile` is not in Alpine packages, I think it'd be easier to install `helmfile` from the releases: https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases. Just `wget` or `curl` the binary and install it it `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks - I've never installed a binary directly like that and was having difficulty to get it to work. Do you have a code snippet I could use in the command line? I'm also confused at to which I need if the base image is linux alpine.

Comment: I have written an answer, hope that helps you :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the use case – why would you want to use Helmfile, a tool for installing applications in Kubernetes, inside a Docker daemon?  If you just need the `docker` CLI and are trying to build an image of tools for some other use case, can you `brew install docker` without trying to combine two images?

Comment: I was battling to get the docker daemon stated in the linuxbrew/brew image. So tried to use another image to get the docker deamon to start. I'm using it as a custom image in an AWS codebuild step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for your case (and since you asked if there is an alternative approach to this problem), it would be easier in your case to have a single stage build, and install the binaries directly from the releases. You would be able to set the versions of your binaries to have reproducible builds. The following `Dockerfile` should work:

```
FROM    docker

RUN     wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/kubectl https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.24.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl \
 &&     chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 &&     wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k3d-io/k3d/main/install.sh | TAG=v5.4.4 sh \
 &&     wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/helmfile https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/download/v0.144.0/helmfile_linux_amd64 \
 &&     chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/helmfile
```

Here, I have set the latest versions at the time of writing (`kubectl` version 1.24.0, `k3d` version 5.4.4, `helmfile` version 0.144.0), but feel free to change them.